# Given two reverse lines and a point outside them, how to prove there exists an unique plane parallel to both of them passing through the given point?

Tags: geometry

Let's call the two reverse lines $r$ and $s$.
Since they are reverse, there is not a line $s'\parallel s$ concurrent to $r$ and there is only one plane $\beta \parallel \alpha$ that contains $P, r$ and  $s'$. Therefore, $r \parallel \beta$

Answer (score 1):

Given two lines $r$ and $s$ which are reverse, we conclude that $r\not\parallel s$ and $r\cap s = \varnothing$.

Consequently, we can choose a point $A\in r$ and consider a line $s'\parallel s$ which passes through $A$.

Since $r$ and $s'$ are concurrent (not parallel), there is an unique plane which contains both $r$ and $s'$.

Let call such plane $\Pi$. Therefore there exists an unique plane $\alpha\parallel \Pi$ which passes through $P$.

Finally, we can conclude that $\alpha\parallel r$ and $\alpha\parallel s$. That is because $\alpha\parallel s'$ and $s'\parallel s$.

Hopefully this helps !